# Python File Can't Write

Tags: python, file-io

I try to make a file transfer script, but it's not working. I receive data, the file is created, but nothing in write in it. In this while block, data are receive once, after that nothing is happend, but the while seems to continue, cause I don't get "File received".

```
def receive_bytes_data(conn,filename):
    with open("new_file.txt", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            receive_b = conn.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)[0]
            f.write(receive_b)
            print(receive_b)
            if not receive_b:
                break 
            print(True)
        f.close()
    print("File received")
```

Comment: It might be the case that receive_b is never false, thus you never exit the while loop

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that it does not write this data in the file.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the wrong file?  The function takes a `filename` argument, but it's never used.  The filename is always `new_file.txt`.

Comment: I understand what the problem is. This loop is infinite and cannot close the file. That's why it doesn't give me the output in it. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

You're not flushing the buffer to the file in your `f.write(..)`, so the process waits until the file is closed before doing so. Since you're in an infinite loop, that will never happen.

Either include `line_buffering=True` in your `f.write(..)`, or specifically call `f.flush()` after writing.

My preference is to use the first choice.

Comment: line buffering would depend on writing a newline, right?  I'm not sure that ever happens.